# Cron job not running to backup mysql database

Tags: mysql, linux, cron, cron-task

I am trying to backup my mysql database using linux crontab like below command,

```
$crontab -e
15 * * * * /usr/bin/mysqldump -u XXX-pXXX demobackupDB > /home/user/DBbackup/$(date +%F)_backup.sql
```

But i dont find that .sql file in the specific folder after every 15 mins.

How to find what is error and fix it?

Comment: can you check in error log?

Comment: @bluto which error log? where it is?

Comment: which server you are using?

Comment: then you can check errors in: `/var/log/apache2/` `error.log` file

Comment: @bluto I checked there but there s nothing error about cron.

Answer (score 2):

You have wrong crontab. What you specified is "run task at 15 minutes after each hour".

You need this crontab to run task every 15 minutes:

```
*/15 * * * * /usr/bin/mysqldump -u XXX-pXXX demobackupDB > /home/user/DBbackup/$(date +%F)_backup.sql
```

If your job is still not running there could be many reasons of this.

You can start debugging with the simple test like this:

```
* * * * * echo hi >> /home/user/test
```

(You should see a new line "hi" appended to `/home/user/test` file once a minute)

If this is not the case see probable reasons for ubuntu here: https://askubuntu.com/q/23009.
Also see cron log: https://askubuntu.com/q/56683/103599

Comment: I tried this too but i dont find .sql file in the DBbackup folder.

Comment: Have you tried to run `mysqldump` command manually in shell? (without crontab)

Comment: No i didnt. How to do that?

Comment: I mean that you can run this command (`/usr/bin/mysqldump -u XXX-pXXX demobackupDB > /home/user/DBbackup/$(date +%F)_backup.sql`) directly in bash to see if there is any problem with it and debug it without involving cron.

Comment: If i execute the command in root user its created .sql file in the specific folder but if i run the command in sudo user then it says permission denied.

Comment: Now if i execute the command manually then .sql file created in that specific folder fine. but in crontan its not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93239/discussion-between-m-manivasagam-and-ks1322).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file with your statement and make it executable

```
echo '/usr/bin/mysqldump -u XXX-pXXX demobackupDB > /home/user/DBbackup/$(date +%F)_backup.sql' > backupjob
```

Make them executable

```
chmod +x backupjob
```

And run it

```
sudo ./backupjob
```

If everything is fine, the mysql-backup-file should be created. If not, go on with debugging your statement else change your cronjob entry:

`cronjob -e`

```
# My MySQL-Backup-Job
*/15 * * * * /yourpath/backup
...
```

**Important**: The Crontab-Table must end with an empty line!

For further Informations: [Ubuntu - Cron](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto)